# Printing a packed BCD (DT) - assembly language (TASM)

Tags: assembly, calculator, tasm, bcd

I tried to make a simple calculator in assembly. I used TASM(school policy). The problem is printing a number saved with FBSTP command(co-processor command) in a DT variable.

> FBSTP adr - Stores at the address „adr” the value located on top of the
>   stack (ST (0)) as a packed decimal number (defined at “adr”
>   with DT). The stack pointer is decremented. The conversion
>   is done during the store process.

I debugged the program and when dividing with 10 the result gets corrupted. For example:
12*1=12. The result in res2 is correct. After moving it to AX it's still correct but when 
I divide it by 10 DX becomes 8 instead of 2 so instead of 12 it prints 18. I also noticed
that 12h=18d but I can't make the connection.
LE: If I use a simple integer store in a word variable and print that one it works fine.

Here is the part of code that i think counts:

```
multiplication:
FINIT
FILD x
FILD y
FMUL
FBSTP res2
FWAIT
MOV ax,WORD PTR res2
call write
jmp_line
jmp exit  


write       PROC    NEAR ;my printing proc moves cursor x spaces and starts writing
                          from back to front

    PUSH    DX
            PUSH    AX
    PUSH    CX
    MOV     CX,0

    CMP     AX, 0;check sign
    JNS     ok_write
    NEG     AX ;negate if <0
    MOV     CX,1 ;used to know if number is negative


ok_write:
    printspace ;macro that jumps 5 spaces(maximum number length)
    ;starts printing the number backwards
    print_digit:
    inc len
    ;print each digit
    MOV DX,0 ;prepare DX for storing the remeinder
    DIV CS:ten ;divide AX by 10 so that the last digit of the number is stored
    ADD dl,30h ;transform to ascii
    PUSH AX ;save AX
    MOV ah,02h
    INT 21h  ;print last digit
    printchar   8 ;put cursor over last printed digit
    printchar   8 ;move cursor in front of last printed digit

    cmp divi,1  ;
    JNE not_div
    cmp len,1
    JNE not_div
    printchar '.'
    printchar   8
    printchar   8

    not_div:
    POP AX ;retreive AX
    CMP AX,0 ;when AX=0 the number is written
    JNE print_digit
    ;/print each digit
    CMP     CX,1
    JNE     end_print
    printchar   '-'
   end_print:

    POP     CX
    POP     AX
    POP     DX
    RET
  write       ENDP
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I haven't analyzed the entire code that you posted, but one odd thing is this: `DIV CS:ten`. If `ten` is in the data segment and `CS` isn't the same as `DS` you may be dividing by something different than `ten`. Try dividing by a register preloaded with 10, e.g. `mov si, 10`+`div si`.

Answer (score 0):

You load a BCD number in AX. BCD means binary coded decimal. so each 4 bit is in fact a decimal value.  You divide by 10, also decimal. But AX treats numbers as hexadecimal.
If you try to divide 12 (bcd) by 10 (decimal) then 12 wil be treated as hexadecimal and the decimal value is 18. 18 divided by 10 (decimal) or 0Ah gives indeed at the end 18 decimal.
If 12 is bcd you only have to convert from packed bcd (each 4 bits is a decimal coded in hexadecimal) to unpacked (each 8 bits represents one decimal digit).
To make things easier: if AX contains 12(bcd) then you can and AX with 0Fh to get the 2 out of it and and ax with 0F0h to get the 1 out of it.
For the digits you simply add 30h ("0") to it. For the tents you shr ax 4 bits and add 30h ("0") to it.
Again: if you convert the packed bcd in AX = 12 to unpacked BCD in AX = 0102 and add 3030h to it, AX will contain the ASCII of 12(bcd).
To store this to print it on screen you must be aware the lower 8 bits will be stored in lower addresses in memory.
Therefore swith AH and AL with xchg AH, AL thus AX = 3231h and store in a memory location in DS.
For numbers that are bigger than 99(bcd) you should use the same technique to extract hundreds, thousands etc....
I hope this will clear things up.